# How do I give KO an array inside my JSON data

Tags: knockout.js

How do I access the internal array in my JSON data?  I'm only showing the first element in the `Scores`, there are many in the real data.  Do I really need to iterate the initialData by hand to get at this internal array?

```
var initialData = {
    "DateId": 32,
    "Scores": [{
        "Alias": "Joyce",
        "MemberId": 11,
        "Game1": 220
    }...]
};
var theScores = initialData.Scores;
var viewModel = {
    scores: ko.observableArray(theScores)
};
```

Comment: Can you show what you mean by iterate the `initialData`. I'm not following that part. `Scores` is an array so won't `initialData.Scores[x]` get you an element from it?

Comment: Scores[0] gives me Joyce's data,  I want ALL of them .. Joyce is just the first element of many .. I'm new to JavaScript and was hoping there was a Scores[] or Scores[*]....

Comment: `Scores` *is* all of the score data. It can be passed around like any other variable, like you have done with `theScores`.

Comment: My problem is that the above code produces an empty array for KO: in Firebug  >>> viewModel Object { scores=[0]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scores` is now an observableArray.  To access the underlying array you would need to retrieve the value of the observable like `viewModel.scores()`.

observableArrays do have the majority of the array methods added to them, so you can do things like `push` or `splice` directly on the observableArray.  This will perform the action and then notify any subscribers that there was a change.

So, basically if you are trying to spit out your array in firebug, then do `viewModel.scores()`.  A handy trick to unwrap all of the observables in a structure is to do `ko.toJS(viewModel)`.  This will give you back a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: something is obviously (not to me) wrong with what I'm doing.  If I remove ko.observableArray and just use theScores the debugger shows viewModel.scores to have data with ko.observableArray scores is empty.

Comment: thanks for your help .. I had a number of newbie issues that where causing problems. The one I don't understand but will just except is that loading jquery.tmpl.js after knockout-1.2.1.js causes KO to choke.  I'm up and running with real data now ... thanks again for your patience and help!